# Build Errors - 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' Conflicts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to 'build' my MVC3 web app in VS2010 however keep getting the following error:

Error   2   The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll'  C:\Users\brownp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Cab\Cab\Models\AccountModels.cs   223 28  Cab

Also, every time I open the solution, it prompts me with the following:

[image: VS2010 error when opening solution]

I install via Web Platform Installer and it installs successfully however the message reappears every time I open the solution.

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After installing MVC4 beta today, a few of my MVC 3 projects would not compile.  (ModelClientValidationRule conflict) The fix was:

Edit:

```
ProjectName.csproj
```

Change

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages"/>
```

To

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/>
```

Comment: I was finally able to validate that just adding Version=1.0.0.0 is sufficient. Thus <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0" />

Comment: for MVC5 use version=2.0.0.0

Comment: Selecting `System.Web.WebPages` in References list, and changing `Specific Version` property to `False` worked for me.

Comment: @EvgenyGorb   --  for MVC 3, 4 or 5  ?    ... Just for everyone's benefit.  thx

Comment: @TomStickel - I used it for MVC 4, but I guess it will fit to other versions too

Comment: @EvgenyGorb    NP ,  I noticed the comment with SO alerts... and since I answered this over 4 years ago I figured for the benefit of the community that I would ask you.   Thx!

Answer (score 13):

Ok try this solution...

1. In the root Web.config file, add a new  entry with the key webPages:Version and the value 1.0.0.0.

   ```
   <appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
   </appSettings>
   ```

`2.In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and then select Unload Project. Then right-click the name again and select Edit ProjectName.csproj.`

`3.Locate the following assembly references:`

```
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers" />
```

Replace them with the following:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/>
```

4.Save the changes, close the project (.csproj) file you were editing, and then right-click the project and select Reload.

REFERENCE: http://forums.asp.net/t/1723108.aspx/1

also try: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815

Answer (score 10):

Delete `System.Web.WebPages` from solution references. It is all.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to avoid this conflict is-

1. Go to solution explorer
2. Reference
3. Right click on `System.Web.WebPages`
4. Remove

Now run your application and Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

This issue, which is the same as you described in VS2010, occurred in my case in VS2015 with a newer version of MVC (V5).

Here's how I was able to fix it:

- Update the NUGET packages to the latest version.
- In your project, remove the references for Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages. Then, re-add reference by using the latest package (use "Browse..."):

  > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40
- Ensure that all projects are referencing the same assembly, if not, fix them as described above. Then, re-build the solution. In my case, it fixed the error.

Check the `Web.config` file, and fix settings such as:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
...
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```