# MVC 4 Beta side by side installation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I just installed the MVC 4 Beta now my MVC 3 application does not compile with the following error:

> The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll'    C:\Users\michaeljo\Documents\src\patientgive\Phc.Mvc\Infrastructure\PasswordStrengthAttribute.cs

It would appear this has been moved to a different assembly and since both assemblies are in the GAC it does not know which to use.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

After installing MVC4 beta today, a few of my MVC 3 projects would not compile.  (ModelClientValidationRule conflict) The fix was:

Edit:

```
ProjectName.csproj
```

Change

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages"/>
```

To

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/>
```

Comment: @MSajjadi  I get so much from StackOverflow, that I'm happy to give back.

Answer (score 4):

Ok try this solution...

In the root Web.config file, add a new entry with the key webPages:Version and the value 1.0.0.0.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

2.In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and then select Unload Project. Then right-click the name again and select Edit ProjectName.csproj.

3.Locate the following assembly references:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages"/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers" />
```

Replace them with the following:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/>
```

4.Save the changes, close the project (.csproj) file you were editing, and then right-click the project and select Reload.

[REFERENCE](http://forums.asp.net/t/1723108.aspx/1)

also try [this](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815)

I Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512021/) for me the second edit combined with the first solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the reference of System.Web.WebPages. This will build your project successfully.