# System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' exists in both locations error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC 4 Beta side by side installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471263/mvc-4-beta-side-by-side-installation-error)

I get this error

> Error 1    The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' exists in
>   both  'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
>   Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll'  and 'c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll'

After I have changed `Copy Local` to **false** for some ASP .NET MVC3 DLLs

How can I stop this error from occurring?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471263/mvc-4-beta-side-by-side-installation-error it worked