# MVC 3 Stops working after MVC4 Installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, build

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC 4 Beta side by side installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471263/mvc-4-beta-side-by-side-installation-error)

I have an MVC3 application in progress. I want to start another application in MVC4. But MVC 3 application stopped working after MVC 4 installation(not beta). getting some dll conflicting errors. One of the error is like this.

```
The type 'System.Web.Helpers.Json' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL    \System.Web.Helpers\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Helpers.dll' and 'c:\Windows    \Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Helpers    \v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Helpers.dll' `at      System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean    noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean    ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context,    VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile,    Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath,    HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String   virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations)
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine e)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)`
```

what would be a fix for this?

Comment: Shall I follow this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471263/mvc-4-beta-side-by-side-installation-error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815)

Installing ASP.NET MVC 4  breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM applications. ASP.NET MVC 3 applications that were created with the RTM release (not with the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update release) require the following changes in order to work side-by-side with ASP.NET MVC 4. Building the project without making these updates results in compilation errors.
Required updates

In the root Web.config file, add a new  entry with the key webPages:Version and the value 1.0.0.0.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and then select Unload Project. Then right-click the name again and select Edit ProjectName.csproj.
Locate the following assembly references:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages"/> 
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers" />
```

Replace them with the following:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/> 
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Save the changes, close the project (.csproj) file you were editing, and then right-click the project and select Reload.

(You can manually edit the MVC project file in **text editor** also. Right click the .csproj file and open with any text editor and edit carefully the xml)

Comment: Thanks! In my case i just had to replace the **<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers" />** line in the .csproj, then recompile and it did works!... much appreciated.