# Deploying MVC 3 application in MVC 4 hosted IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created MVC 3 application, everything is working fine.

Now we moved for deployment. However the IIS 7 got already installed with MVC 4 and running other MVC 4 application.

Can I simply host my MVC 3 application? Or do I need to do any changes in `web.config`, or `global.asax` etc? Any breakdown will happen?

I developed MVC 3 with Razor.

Comment: Have you tried hosting the MVC3 application?

Comment: @Yakimych, Before hosting i am asking here. That's the production server.  I need to be careful on issues :(

Comment: You are right, of course you should be careful with those issues. I would recommend setting up a (virtual) environment similar to your production server and trying it out first. If it doesn't work, I'd say it's a good candidate for asking here. I don't think it is a good idea to go all in on a production server (without testing) even if you get a positive answer here, do you? ;) Also, backing up your production environment before making drastic changes would be wise.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me the backup. Its done already. All my worry is i have seen a assembly redirect section for MVC 2 to MVC 3 in web.config. Its fine. The same will work for MVC 3 to 4? any more unexpected breaking changes? I believe all the latest version should support earlier versions. Thats Microsoft policy(Specially seeing their support for Internet Explorer). So expecting same here.

Answer (score 1):

You can install MVC3 and and MVC4 side by side, but you may need to follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471263/mvc-4-beta-side-by-side-installation-error.)

If you don't want to install MVC3 on the server, simply BIN deploy it and make the changes in the attached link. That way you'll risk no knock on effects to other apps.