# asp.net MVC 3 solution doesnt work after opening in VS 12

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I created an asp.net MVc 3 application using Visual studio 2010. It was working fine. I uploaded to hosting which has asp.net MVc 3 installed and it worked. I opened this MVC 3 solution in visual studio 2012. At that time, It did some up gradation. It created

```
151Marketing.v11.suo
UpgradeLog.html
UpgradeLog.xml

and a folder named _UpgradeReport_Files and backup folder.
```

When I publish this on live server, I get errors of framework. I see a backup folder as wel as I guess it was created before conversion by VS 12. Should I use that or is there any other way to change the current version of code to work on hosting because after i opened it in VS 12, I made several changes as well.

Please suggest

Comment: It would be more helpful if you post the actual error. Also, what did you upload exactly? I seriously hope you didn't upload the files you've mentioned. Can you run the project local, i.e.  debug it or do you get the same errors?

Comment: Any luck?  Can you provide error?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your MVC3 project got updated to MVC4.

Replace the Project type GUID with the old mvc3 ones (in your .csproj file):

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

If that's the case, be careful with the used referenced libraries (version).

If you use MVC4, you should localcopy the assemblies into the /bin directory.
Also, it might have switched to the 4.5 Framework. 
You might want to take that down to 4.0. MVC4 also works fine with framework 4.0 by the way.

If that doesn't work, you'll probably better create a new MVC3 project, and copy all the cshtml and Controllers over (not the web.config) from the old project.

If you have administrative rights, you can also install the asp.net mvc4 update for Visual Studio 2010.
If you don't want to localcopy the MVC4 assemblies, you might want to install the MVC4 runtime on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your web.config and see if the references for MVC got upgraded to MVC4.  If so, revert those back to MVC3 references.

Seems like a good way I found to deal with upgrades is to backup in a folder the solution and projects etc... and then when you are upgrading /opening/converting to using vs 2012,  you can can use "Beyond Compare" or WinMerge" or another comparison tool and see what files got changed.

If any files got changed it will be .sln / .csproj / web.config   etc...

I had problem with going from MVC 3 to MVC 4 beta and I posted here: [MVC 4 Beta side by side installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471263/mvc-4-beta-side-by-side-installation-error/9551777#9551777)

Your problem is different, but I would probably start with web.config

You may have had setting in vs 2010 mvc 3 like this:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Now perhaps it looks like this?

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```