# Error throws using ModelClientValidationRule in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation-controls

I try to do the custom client side validation in MVC 5 Project. When I add the following code:

```
 public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
 {
    //Some Validation Here
 }
```

I get the following error :

> The type name 'ModelClientValidationRule' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

But when I check the `web.config` file, I am using WebPages version supported from 0.0

```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Can you try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512021/build-errors-system-web-mvc-modelclientvalidationrule-conflicts/9681709#9681709

Answer (score 0):

My `System.Web.Mvc` got deleted and when I added it back, it started giving me this error that you have mentioned. The reason for it was that, earlier I was using `System.Web.Mvc [3.0.0.1]`, which got deleted and while adding back, I added `System.Web.Mvc [4.0.0.1]`. So, to fix this issue, I deleted `System.Web.Mvc [4.0.0.1]` and added `System.Web.Mvc [3.0.0.1]`.