# System.Web.Mvc missing reference to ModelClientValidationRule

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write some client validation in a class library. I added a reference to System.Web.Mvc on my local machine here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll` but I am getting the error

> The type or namespace ModelClientValidationRule could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am targeting .Net Framework 4 and [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelclientvalidationrule(v=vs.100).aspx) indicates that should be correct, so I am little stumped as the why the error is occurring.

I am using VS2013 and have .Net 4.5 on my local machine, and have written client validation in other projects. I expect that I could resolve this issue by adding the MVC NuGet package, but I would like to explore the alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Errors - 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' Conflicts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512021/build-errors-system-web-mvc-modelclientvalidationrule-conflicts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While ModelClientValidationRule is in the namespace System.Web.Mvc, it is in the assembly System.Web.WebPages, so you need to reference that assembly too.

Comment: For future reference: if you have a similar problem in the future look at the msdn page for the class you need it will name the assembly the class is in.

Comment: Please view 
http://grandhah.blogspot.in/2015/07/add-custom-validation-condition-to-data.html 
I have explained the custom validation for data annotation

Comment: @NilsO: It is not always that easy (I wish it was) - in my case, the error occurred after doing a NUGET update of MVC - although System.Web.MVC.dll was updated, ModelClientValidationRule was no longer available. Referencing the old DLL fixes the issue, but I want to use the new one. I am still looking for a solution - no luck in MSDN or via Mr.Google so far. Similar question (no answer yet): [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29208111/1016343)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nils answer, you may need to add Microsoft.ASP.NET.MVC package from NuGet.